# How to sort an out-of-order event time stream using Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970488/how-to-sort-a-stream-by-event-time-using-flink-sql) covers how to sort an out-of-order stream using Flink SQL, but I would rather use the DataStream API. [One solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47582271/2000823) is to do this with a ProcessFunction that uses a PriorityQueue to buffer events until the watermark indicates they are no longer out-of-order, but this performs poorly with the RocksDB state backend (the problem is that each access to the PriorityQueue will require ser/de of the entire PriorityQueue). How can I do this efficiently regardless of which state backend is in use?

Answer (score 13):

A better approach (which is more-or-less what is done internally by Flink's SQL and CEP libraries) is to buffer the out-of-order stream in MapState, as follows:

If you are sorting each key independently, then first key the stream. Otherwise, for a global sort, key the stream by a constant so that you can use a KeyedProcessFunction to implement the sorting.

In the `open` method of that process function, instantiate a MapState object, where the keys are timestamps and the values are lists of stream elements all having the same timestamp.

In the `onElement` method:

- If an event is late, either drop it or send it to a side output
- Otherwise, append the event to entry of the map corresponding to its timestamp
- Register an event time timer for this event's timestamp

When `onTimer` is called, then the entries in the map for this timestamp are ready to be released as part of the sorted stream -- because the current watermark now indicates that all earlier events should have already been processed. Don't forget to clear the entry in the map after sending the events downstream.

Comment: why does sorting need to happen in a KeyedProcessFunction? why cant a regular ProcessFunction be used for a global sort?

Comment: Because only a KeyedProcessFunction can use event time timers, and because it's convenient to be able to use keyed state. But you could implement a global sort using a custom operator along with operator state.

Comment: So the value type is probably a ArrayList. Does flink do ser/de for every element appended into the list? Is it costly?

Comment: Yes, that is potentially costly, but only if there are a significant number of hash collisions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the solution with timers did not work for us. It led to checkpoints failing due to huge amount of timers being generated. As an alternative, we did a sort with tumbling windows:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.*;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.PrintSinkFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.flink.util.OutputTag;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class EventSortJob {
    private static final Duration ALLOWED_LATENESS = Duration.ofMillis(2);
    private static final Duration SORT_WINDOW_SIZE = Duration.ofMillis(5);

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventSortJob.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> source = env
                .fromElements(0, 1, 2, 10, 9, 8, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6)
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                        new WatermarkStrategy<Integer>() {
                            @Override public WatermarkGenerator<Integer> createWatermarkGenerator(WatermarkGeneratorSupplier.Context context) {
                                return new WatermarkGenerator<Integer>() {
                                    private long watermark = Long.MIN_VALUE;

                                    // punctuated watermarks are used here for demonstration purposes only!!!
                                    @Override public void onEvent(Integer event, long eventTimestamp, WatermarkOutput output) {
                                        long potentialWatermark = event - ALLOWED_LATENESS.toMillis(); // delay watermark behind latest timestamp
                                        if (potentialWatermark > watermark) {
                                            watermark = potentialWatermark;
                                            output.emitWatermark(new Watermark(watermark));
                                            LOGGER.info("watermark = {}", watermark);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // normally, periodic watermarks should be used
                                    @Override public void onPeriodicEmit(WatermarkOutput output) {}
                                };
                            }

                            @Override public TimestampAssigner<Integer> createTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssignerSupplier.Context context) {
                                return (element, recordTimestamp) -> element; // for simplicity, element values are also timestamps (in millis)
                            }
                        }
                );

        OutputTag<Integer> lateEventsTag = new OutputTag<Integer>("lateEventsTag") {};
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> sorted = source
                .keyBy(v -> 1)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(SORT_WINDOW_SIZE.toMillis())))
                .sideOutputLateData(lateEventsTag)
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override public void process(
                            Integer integer,
                            ProcessWindowFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer, TimeWindow>.Context context,
                            Iterable<Integer> elements,
                            Collector<Integer> out
                    ) {
                        StreamSupport.stream(elements.spliterator(), false)
                                .sorted()
                                .forEachOrdered(out::collect);
                    }
                });

        source.keyBy(v -> 1).map(v -> String.format("orig: %d", v)).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());
        sorted.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());
        sorted.getSideOutput(lateEventsTag).keyBy(v -> 1).map(v -> String.format("late: %d", v)).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());

        env.execute();
    }
}
```