# Flink Timer Timestamp

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Do timers in Flink get fired if they are set to a timestamp in the past? Since the current timestamp is greater than that of the timer service, would it get fired immediately or never get fired?

Also, we are trying to sort/order input events based on the event time by collecting/buffering them in a processing time based tumbling window just so we don't have to drop late events. Are there are any better solutions to address this?

Answer (score 1):

Timers set to a timestamp in the past get triggered ASAP.

For sorting, see [How to sort an out-of-order event time stream using Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468154/how-to-sort-an-out-of-order-event-time-stream-using-flink) and [How to sort a stream by event time using Flink SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970488/how-to-sort-a-stream-by-event-time-using-flink-sql).