# How to sort or join a KeyedStream by time?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a  data stream using **keyBy** and then **flatMap**. How can I want to write the output to a queue and preserve time order across all keys?

```
dataSrc // just a stream of longs
    .keyBy(value -> value % 4)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
    .flatMap((value1, value2) -> 
        {
            if (value2.longValue > value1.longValue) {
                return value2;
            }
            return value1;
        });
```

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/59468154/2000823 will help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The suggestion is good. Is it the most Flinky way of doing it?

Comment: Using Flink SQL, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970489/2000823, is probably the best solution.