# ProcessingTime windows for idle streams in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

After processing a stream with keyed state based operators, our stream cannot be guaranteed to be ordered anymore.

Thus, I implemented a sorting operator which utilizes windows of processing time to buffer stream elements and emit them in a sorted way.
I read [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468154/how-to-sort-an-out-of-order-event-time-stream-using-flink) which uses timers and a map state. However, I was afraid of registering a lot of timers and adapted a [window based solution](https://gist.github.com/mrsimpson/70fccac3d52bebbe319c6d488d4db949) as [suggested by one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73011990/6141374).

It can be generically inserted into the pipeline  like this:

```java
someStream
        .keyBy(k -> 1)
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
        .process(
            new BufferedSorter<SomePojo, Integer>() {
              @Override
              protected TypeInformation<VehicleEvent> getTypeInfo() {
                return TypeInformation.of(SomePojo.class);
              }

              @Override
              protected Timestamp getTime(SomePojo element) {
                return element.getEventTime();
              }
            })
```

While this works fine given the proper heuristics for the accepted processing time latency, I noticed that *the WindowProcessFunction is not executing for idle input streams*.

Once I publish an element to the stream, the window gets triggered (independent of the event time of the element).
This is counter-intuitive to me, as I expected the window to be triggered by the pure advancing of the processing time.

Answer (score 1):

The details of your scenario aren't clear, but here are the pertinent facts:

- Windows are created lazily, when the first event is assigned to them. Empty windows don't exist, and can't be triggered.
- Processing time windows are triggered when the system clock reaches the designated time.

I wonder if perhaps you are using ingestion-time logic for part of your pipeline, rather than processing time, which might be causing some confusion.

Comment: In general, our application is an event time based application. But some streams are idle for minutes due to batch-based insertion into the source (Kafka) topic. I added some more explanation to the origin question so that the context hopefully becomes more clear.
But on an idle stream, the current processing time window may be empty, so there won't be an evaluation given the lazy character you explained. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, [RTFM for the laziness](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#window-assigners): "In a nutshell, a window is created as soon as the first element that should belong to this window arrives, and the window is completely removed when the time (event or processing time) passes its end timestamp plus the user-specified allowed lateness"